# I am trying to test a program that prints a shipping rate based on yes or no answers

Tags: python

The problem with this program is that the if/else statements are not working properly. When the answer is "yes", the problem also prints the question for when the answer is "no". Another problem is that it's not printing the rate1 when it's supposed to.

```
# This program calculates the shipping cost as shown in the slide
international = input("Are you shipping internationally (yes or no)? ")
rate1 = 5
rate2 = 10

if international.upper() == "yes":
    shippingRate = rate2
else:
    continental = input("Are you shipping continental (yes or no)? ")
    if continental.upper() == "yes":
        shippingRate = rate1
    else:
        shippingRate = rate2
        
print("The shipping rate is " + ("%.2f" % shippingRate))
```

Comment: Tip: Think in terms of structured data not just heaps of repetitive code and arbitrary variable names. Use `rate[1]` vs. `rate2`. Even better: `rates = { 'local': 5, 'international': 10 }`.

Comment: Also, a much shorter and more elegant way to print the shipping rate using f-strings would be `print(f"The shipping rate is {shippingRate:.2f}")`.

Comment: Typo: `"yes" != "YES"`

Answer (score 1):

I notice you're using a `.upper()` that would not ever equal "yes"

Cause `upper()` won't ever return lowercase letters.

But this code might work with `== "YES"`.

Comment: Or `.lower()`, ofcourse.

Comment: dude thanks!!! I realized my error right away.

Comment: Use `casefold` instead of `upper` or `lower`.

Answer (score -3):

Make it easier and get rid of the `rate1` and `rate2` variables. Heres the working code:

```
# This program calculates the shipping cost as shown in the slide
international = input("Are you shipping internationally (yes or no)? ")
shippingRate = 0

if international.lower().startswith('y'):
    shippingRate = 10
else:
    continental = input("Are you shipping continental (yes or no)? ")
    if continental.lower().startswith('y'):
        shippingRate = 5
    else:
        shippingRate = 10
        
print("The shipping rate is " + ("%.2f" % shippingRate))
```

Comment: No, actually **don't** do this. What if this code was more complex and used the rates in multiple different parts? You would have to change the value for _every single occurrence_, which is not only cumbersome but error-prone. Use variables for constants in a program.

Comment: According to the OP, This is the only code he presented so that wouldn't apply.

Comment: Even in this small case, it requires changing the rate twice. Even if in the slightest, don't make code less maintainable. And how would this not set a bad precedence? Also, when did OP state that this was the final program?